# String Manipulation in C#, Avoiding the right char, wrong place

Tags: c#, string

I'm developing an app thats used for receiving a feed and presenting the data in a much nicer way. Currently I fetch the string, pass the string to a method that changes it into a list to make the data more easier to access. This was working fine throughout my app until I encountered this problem.

Sample Data:

> [{"FirstName":"Bill","LastName":"Jones","UserName":"ourbilly","Played":"game306","Win":1.40,"City":"UK"}]

The above data would be broken down and presented like such

```
KEY | Value
FirstName : Bill
LastName : Jones
UserName : ourbilly
Played : game306
Win : 1.40
City : UK
```

This works, this is perfect. However I've just encountered a problem.. What if the value or key itself contained : inside of it.. for example

> [{"FirstName":"Bi:ll","LastName":"Jones","UserName":"our:billy","Played":"game306","Win":1.40,"City":"UK"}]

The above data would be broken down and presented like such

```
KEY | Value
FirstName : Bi
ll : LastName
Jones : UserName
our : billy
Played : game306
Win : 1.40
City : UK
```

Which is actually incorrect, I'm unsure how to tackle this problem.. Below is the code that I'm using for making this list and for clearing up the string before returning it to present

```
public static ListWithDuplicates FetchFieldData(string data)
 {
    string[] words = cleanString(data).Split(':');

    var list = new ListWithDuplicates();

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length;i++)
    {
        list.Add(words[i], words[i + 1]);
        i++;
    }

    return list;
}

private static string cleanString(string messyString)
{
    string[] toRemove ={ "{", "}", "\\", "\"", "[", "]" };

    foreach (var s in toRemove)
    {
        messyString = messyString.Replace(s, "");
    }
    messyString = messyString.Replace(",", ":");
    return messyString;
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own JSON parser from scratch?

Comment: Practice and learning really, I'm not aiming to do anything fancy.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty with Regex; but it looks like you need a negative lookahead to be sure what you're trying to parse isn't between balanced quotations.

Comment: Personally, I would use a JSON parser that is already available. But if you want to learn how to parse complicated strings without writing a bunch of complicated looping code, you should look at regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/. You can extract just the bits out of the string you want and support multiple different format permutations.

Comment: @NightOwl888 No, regexes are not the solution to this problem, because handling an escaped `\"` is a pain.

Comment: @xanatos - To the contrary, handling escaping characters is quite simple. You just need to prefix the string with a `@`. And making a Regex to pull repeating sections out of a string is easier than creating code that filters out certain characters, replaces certain characters, and does lots of other looping.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Building a regex that handle things like `\\\\\"` vs `\\\\"` (the first one are two escaped backslashes plus an escaped double quote, while the second is two escaped backslashes plus the closing double quotes) isn't really simple. Surely doable, but not immediate. Something like `"([^\\"]|\\.)*"` probably

Comment: Well, like I said I would favor an existing JSON parser to regex. In fact, for any standard text format I would use an existing parser. I would only resort to a regex if I were dealing with a complex format and I was sure the amount of text is a sufficiently small amount so that it wouldn't be a performance bottleneck. I only mentioned regex because the OP said he wanted to learn a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this isn't the thing you asked, but it's the thing I'll give you :-) Often on Stackoverflow there are [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)s :-) )

You should deserialize it as a JSON object:

```
string str = @"[{""FirstName"":""Bill"",""LastName"":""Jones"",""UserName"":""ourbilly"",""Played"":""game306"",""Win"":1.40,""City"":""UK""}]";
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer(); // System.Web.Extensions assembly
object[] obj = (object[])jss.DeserializeObject(str);
Dictionary<string, object> dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)obj[0];
```

(or probably better by using the JSON.NET library)

This will save the pain of handling all the "special" cases: escaped `\"`, `\\`, unicode characters `\u0025` and so on

Comment: This looks to be working perfectly, Just one question. say that obj contains more than 1, whats the best approach to adding this to that dictionary?

Comment: @Andy there will be multiple dictionaries, `obj[0]`, `obj[1],` ... all with `FirstName`, `LastName`, ... a simple `for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++) { var dict =  (Dictionary<string, object>)obj[i]; ... }` will do

Comment: So is it not possible to get this all in one dictionary and return that?, Originally I was using a list which allowed duplicates to prevent the duplicate key problem.

Comment: @Andy You can convert the dictionaries to a list, but it depends on how the data is structured. You should ask another question on this (with a full example of multiple items)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this overload of Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve correct result in following way:

1. First, split by "," to get all key-value pairs on form of key":"value,
2. Split each pair by ":".

In code:

```
var list = new ListWithDuplicates();
var pairs = data.Split(new[] {"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    list.AddRange(pair.Split(new[] {"\":\""}, StringSplitOptions.None));
}
```